# Do challenge runs count towards Isaac's completion achievements?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Challenges 9 and 10, Isaac was good today and The purist, require you to kill respectively Satan and Isaac. Do these kills count towards Isaac's achievements, Mom's Knife and The D20?

Comment: This is indeed interesting. Too bad I can't figure this one out myself (I have already beaten both Satan and Isaac as Isaac).

Comment: @Aubergine Me too, that's why I'm asking... I could try playing the game back from scratches, but it would take too long.

Comment: well you _could_ delete your progress and start anew...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. I got the achievement for beating Isaac with Isaac after doing it in a challenge.